# How to use GLS in Python's statsmodel and specify a certain correlation structure: (CorARMA in R)

Tags: python, r, regression, statsmodels

**Summary**
I am trying to use 'statsmodels' in Python to fit a GLS model, while specifying a certain autocorrelation structure. In particular I am trying to recreate the following command from R:

```
   model_p10 <- gls(flow ~ time + level + trend,   data=data,  
   correlation=corARMA(p=10,form=~time),   method="ML")
```

**Details**
I am trying to follow a (free) [course on time series intervention analysis](https://www.edx.org/course/policy-analysis-using-interrupted-time-series), taught using R, but instead using Python. I can see that [GLS in Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.GLS.html) does accept other parameters. I am not sure what the Python equivalent of [`corARMA(p=,q=)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-157/topics/corARMA) would be or if I can feed that in to the statsmodels GLS function to recreate the code snippet above.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like the following in Python:

```
GLS(y,X, corARMA(p=,q=)).fit()
```

I have tried playing around with ARIMA in statsmodels, but I am not a statistician and am not sure what I am doing. For my final result I want the plot to be a straight line, and take into account auto regressive and/or moving average term.